# How can I optimise Zumero sync queries

Tags: sql-server, zumero

I am currently experiencing very long sync times on a zumero synced database (well over a minute), and following some profiling, the culprit appears to be a particular query that is taking 20+ seconds (suitably anonymised):

```
WITH relevant_rvs AS
(
  SELECT rv.z_rv AS rv FROM zumero."mydb_089eb7ec0e2e4772ba0dde90170ee368_mysynceddb$z$rv$271340031" rv
  WHERE (rv.txid<=913960)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM zumero."mydb_089eb7ec0e2e4772ba0dde90170ee368_mysynceddb$z$dd$271340031" dd WHERE dd.rv=rv.z_rv AND (dd.txid<=913960))
)
INSERT INTO #final_included_271340031_e021cfbe1c97213dd5adbacd667c08439fb8c6 (z_rv)
SELECT z$this.z_rv
 FROM zumero."mydb_089eb7ec0e2e4772ba0dde90170ee368_mysynceddb$z$271340031" z$this
  WHERE (z$this.z_rv IN (SELECT rv FROM relevant_rvs))
  AND MyID = (MyID = XXX AND MyOtherField=XXX)
UNION SELECT z$this.z_rv
 FROM zumero."mydb_089eb7ec0e2e4772ba0dde90170ee368_mysynceddb$z$old$271340031" z$this
  WHERE (z$this.z_rv IN (SELECT rv FROM relevant_rvs))
  AND (MyID = XXX AND MyOtherField=XXX)
```

I have taken the latter SELECT part of the query and ran it in isolation, which reproduces the same poor performance. Interestingly the execution plan recommends an index be applied, but I'm reluctant to go changing the schema of zumero generated tables, is adding indexes to these tables something that can be attempted safely and is it likely to help?

The source tables have 100,000ish records in them and the filter results in each client syncing 100-1000ish records, so not trivial data volumes but levels I would not expect to be causing major issues in terms of query performance.

Does anyone have any experience optimising Zumero sync performance server side? Do any indexes on source tables propagate to these tables? they don't appear to in this case.

Comment: Curious - what index was suggested by the execution plan?

Comment: @PaulRoub `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [zumero].[mydb_089eb7ec0e2e4772ba0dde90170ee368_mysynceddb$z$old$271340031] ([MyID],[MyOtherField])
INCLUDE ([z_rv])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a custom index on the `z$old` table should be safe. I do hope it helps boost your query performance! (And it would be great to see a comment letting us know if it does or not.)

I believe the only issue such an index may cause would be that it could block certain schema changes on the host table. For example, if you tried to DROP the `[MyOtherField]` column from the host table, the Zumero triggers would attempt to drop the same column from the `z$old` table as well, and the transaction would fail with an error (which might be a bit surprising, since the index is not on the table being directly acted on).

Another thing to consider: It might also help to give this new index a name that will be recognized/helpful if it ever appears in an error message. Then (as always) feel free to contact support@zumero.com with any further questions or issues if they come up.

Comment: Applying the index yielded some very significant performance improvements on syncs, total sync time is now >10 seconds. The only challenge now is to work out how to write a general purpose script that will apply these indexes to the correct table on any of our customer's databases when the table in question has a different name on each DB... Is there a simple way to look up these table names or is it a case of querying system tables?

Comment: The only way I can think off the top of my head of detecting the table would be looking for certain text sequences in the table name and the existence of certain columns within it (to distinguish it from other tables in the same synced schema), which is a bit horrible, so any pointers on a more elegant solution would appreciated!

Comment: The name of the z$old table, e.g., is the DBFile name followed by `$z$old$` followed by the object id of the table. A table's object id can be found using the `OBJECT_ID` function, like so: `SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable', 'U')`

Comment: Thanks, that should help me write a cleaner script for applying the index

Comment: FWIW: A brief note about custom indexes on `z$old` tables has been added to the ZSS Manager documentation in a new "Advanced Tuning" section: http://zumero.com/docs/zumero_for_sql_server_manager.html#advanced-tuning